# How to type this tilde ~ in Mac (I can only type ˜ Using Fn + N) on an Italian Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've seen [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49236/how-to-type-in-the-tilde-character-with-an-apple-international-keyboard) answer, but on my Italian keyboard I've got <kbd><</kbd> between <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> instead of the <kbd>~</kbd>. So, how can I type it?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with fn + n?

Comment: @Gerry it's not the same tilde

Comment: try option and 5

Comment: Despite a keyboard combination, if you don't want to use it by its own, you could still use the **Character picker**. Just press and hold the **N**, for instance, and a pop-Up will show, giving you the option of choosing the **Ñ** letter.

Comment: @Thecafremo  But he doesn't want Ñ, he wants ~, and Character Picker is useless for doing that.

Comment: @TomGewecke I know. That's why it's a comment and not an answer, as I don't know what exactly he's trying to achieve. Plus it might help someone else landing in this page looking for a way of writing **Ñ**.

Answer (score 21):

<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>

[image]

You can show the keyboard viewer from the input menu if it's enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With the italian keyboard you can use  <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

It is left Alt + ^ which will give you tilda sign over Swedish Mac keyboard.

Comment: The question is for the Italian keyboard, not Swedish

Answer (score 1):

Just change the language of your **USA International Keyboard - PC** for **USA**

Comment: You need to say which key/keys it is you type in order to get a tilde for this to be an "answer".

Comment: worked for me, I was in US layout and changing to US international PC was indeed a solution since it changes the behavior when pressing space changing the small tilde to a normal one

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot about writing accents and special characters in macOS with an Italian keyboard. The most comfortable way to do them is to hold <kbd>option</kbd> + press a key.

Specifically, for tilde, as mention above is <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> (try other keys also, you'll be used to it in a while).

There are other special combinations for accents which are:

- <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and a letter for ñ
- <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and a letter for ü
- <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> and a letter for ú
- <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> and a letter for ù
- <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>ì</kbd> and a letter for ô

Answer (score -1):

Using an Italian Keyboard.

The <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> will Also give you a Small Tilde  `˜` as apposed to `~`

Comment: This small tilde is normally used to accent over the other letters.

If you `Option + N` and then for example  `o` you will get `õ`

Not entering another compatible character while the small tilde is highlighted and moving on will leave you with `˜`

Comment: Totally fails to answer the question, tells you how to make the wrong tilde, should be deleted.